# How to get data from ArcGIS webapp into QGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I need this map in QGIS
https://muskoka.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=86bcd910216c409a9538ef7bf599b154

I found a REST server
https://muskoka.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/696feda3bec04dc2beafc6f7d1f2bc53/data?f=json

I added it to QGIS and no errors, no layers
Added referer https://muskoka.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=86bcd910216c409a9538ef7bf599b154
still no layer, clicked on view service info and got JSON with lots of features services
for example
https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/5de347b46ffc43619b74df36ad3faa91/rest/services/Parcel/Parcel_Address_Service_Public/FeatureServer/3
when trying to connect to it receiving 403 error via QGIS

Also got error 403 from browser, when trying to open this link.

But, I saw in browser in network tab this request works from original webapp
google it

So 2 examples, first works OK, second one 403
you can click on them
https://services6.arcgis.com/QBuWyjJyJZDKpVHF/arcgis/rest/services/TW_Herentals/FeatureServer
https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/5de347b46ffc43619b74df36ad3faa91/rest/services/Parcel/Parcel_Address_Service_Public/FeatureServer/3

so how to add data to QGIS?
Maybe I need to ask the GIS department to put some checkboxes in their config?

Comment: use the Huntsville Public Server  https://maps.huntsville.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Public_Map_Services

Comment: This only zoning server for Huntsville. But pacel addressing there the same and not available.  Hmm... looks like it works,, I will try

Comment: Unfortunately this maps working only for Huntsville. trying to import it to QGIS and it limited with Huntsville borders